# Break "Linked" sidebar section into 2 sections (incoming and outgoing)?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[Until recently](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297/can-we-have-linkbacks), I hadn't realized that incoming links to a question will appear in the sidebar.  Would it make sense to split these into two sections.  I would think when there is a canonical answer might have a lot of outgoing links, and incomining links it would be helpful to distinguish between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what context is this helpful? I find it to be "too much information" -- if posts are Linked, they are Linked which means at least one person thinks they are tied together in some way. Knowing if a link is "incoming" or "outgoing", how does that enhance my understanding of the question?

also see:

[Let linked questions have an arrow indicating which question is linking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66651/let-linked-questions-have-an-arrow-indicating-which-question-is-linking)

Comment: Please see my response in the question you reference.

Comment: To answer your question Jeff: "Tied together" imposes symmetry on an inherently asymmetric relation.  One page links *to* another page because that page provides supporting information; a page has a link *from* other pages that use it for supporting information.  Someone seeking further information about something in the page they are on would prefer first to follow links out, not links in.  I agree that having little iconic arrows all over would be busy and perhaps distracting, but what prevents sorting the links by their in/out function?

Comment: In other words, we at GIS.SE are way too DBA oriented to allow something like this to fall through the cracks.